# htaccess ReWriteRule giving 500 error rather than 403

Tags: .htaccess

In my htaccess file I am blocking site access by referer, remote host and user agent but the following list is returning 500 errors rather than 403's.

Is there something wrong with my syntax or is this working as it should?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} baidu\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http(s)://baidu\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} net76\.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 163data\.com\.cn [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} reverse\.completel\.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^.*163data\.com\.cn$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^.*amazonaws\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^.*colocrossing\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^.*contaboserver\.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^.*dedicatedpanel\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/4\.0.\(compatible\;.Synapse\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/4\.0.\(compatible\;\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozlila [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Huawei.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Baiduspider [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Sogou [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Yandex [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AISearchBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} woriobot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} heritrix [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} NetSeer [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Nutch [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} moatbot [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: First thing you always got to do when you get a 500: Check the server error log.

Comment: First thing I checked and there is nothing in the server error log.
Just tried this myself it is says -
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

When I look at the access logs the entries just show a code 500 error.
I thought with an [F] parameter it should just give a 403.

Comment: _“Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.”_ - you’d need to add an exception for that error document, so that it _can_ be served in response to those requests you just forbade, for this error to go away. (Not sure if that is what’s giving the 500 though.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured this one out after all this time.
As per comment from CBroe I need to add this line -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^403err\.php$
```

Otherwise it is in an infinite loop as it rejects itself when trying to redirect to the 403 error page. Hence the 500 error.